# Weizsäcker–Williams approximation

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, relativity, approximations

I'm having some trouble understanding the [Weizsäcker-Williams approximation](https://www.google.com/search?q=weizsaecker+williams+approximation)

What I *think* it is is the following:

I have a charged particle at high speed, close to the speed of light, at this speed relativity starts to take place, and then the field lines of the particle will start to clump up making them almost like a line - i.e. we can see it at a light pulse.

At least, that is what I think it is - but I might be wrong.

What I don't entirely understand is: Why is this a good thing? Why is looking at a light-pulse/photons better than looking at a charged particle?

Comment: You know, I'm not sure I see why this was downvoted...